# Direct3D 11 - Mipmap level selection

Tags: directx, directx11, mipmaps

When we sample a texture resource through an SSO in HLSL, how is the mip level selected for sampling; assuming the texture resource contains mips?

The SSO has parameters that seem to be concerned with the sampling method, but I can't find any documentation anywhere that states how to actually select a mip level.

Or is it done automatically as a function of the NDC depth value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the standard `Sample` method, the automatic MIP level selection is actually quite complex.  Assuming standard tri-linear sampling of a 2D texture, two MIP levels are actually sampled.  The hardware determines which ones by looking at the texture coordinate arguments of four adjacent pixel shader invocations (referred to as a "quad"), and calculates the difference in `u` and `v` coordinates.  The two MIP levels that are selected are the ones such that the average delta in `u` and `v` equate to just over one texel (the coarser level), and the one that the delta equates to just under one texel (the finer level).  Using the `uv` coordinates at those two MIP levels, the hardware interpolates between the 8 texels to produce the final output color.

This works well for most cases, but if you have a surface that is nearly parallel to the direction of the camera, the difference between the `u` and `v` deltas is actually quite large, so tri-linear sampling can make things look blurry.  This is where anisotropic filtering comes in, which uses a much more complicated formula for choosing the MIP levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SampleLevel` to manually select the mip level. The 3rd parameter specifies the mip level.

[Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb509699(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, `SampleLevel` allows you to pick the MIP level manually, but that doesn't answer the original question, which seems to be asking how *automatic* MIP level selection works.  Also, `SampleLevel` is usually a bad idea unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for selecting a mip level in Direct3D 9 and beyond.

Direct3D 11 has a lot to offer in selecting the mip level.

However, in Direct3D9, which a lot of us still use due to the wide range of platforms it is supported, the trick was to use the

```
SetSamplerState(Index, D3DSAMP_MIPMAPLODBIAS, PCardinal(@Value)^);
```

and

```
SetSamplerState(Index, D3DSAMP_MAXMIPLEVEL, PCardinal(@Value)^);
```

(the above is in Delphi/Object Pascal notation, but is easy to see how it would be in C++)

Say for example you want to use only the 3rd mip level. You should execute:

```
SetSamplerState(Index, D3DSAMP_MAXMIPLEVEL, 3); 

SetSamplerState(Index, D3DSAMP_MIPMAPLODBIAS, -1000);
```

The above forces the max mip level to 3 (instead of 0), and then forces the bias to -1000 so that level 3 is always selected.